# Email - We will discuss about this during/in our meeting scheduled on Monday?

Tags: grammar, sentence, word-formation

I am responding to an email where i want inform the person who asked some question saying we will discuss about this during Mondays meeting. I am not sure which is the correct way of framing this sentence.

> 1) Thanks for providing the details. We will discuss about this in our Monday meeting. Thank you
>
> 2) Thanks for providing the details. We will discuss about this in our Monday's meeting. Thank you
>
> 3) Thanks for providing the details. We will discuss about this during our Monday's meeting. Thank you
>
> 4) Thanks for providing the details. We will discuss about this during our Monday meeting. Thank you

Please suggest if there are any other better options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say "discuss about". "discuss" means "talk about", so "discuss about" would be like saying "talk about about".

Regarding the second part: you can use "in or "during", they're interchangeable in this context.  But, "our Monday's meeting" is wrong: say either "Monday's meeting" or "our Monday meeting".  The latter makes "Monday" sound like the title of the meeting, and would only most appropriate if you have a meeting every Monday morning.  If this isn't the case, say "Monday's meeting" or "our meeting on Monday".